# Grunt my code is duplicated in concat.js

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Here is my grunt config file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

    grunt.initConfig({
        uglify: {
            build: {
                src: 'app/concat.js',
                dest: 'app/concat.min.js'
            }
        },

        concat: {
            options: {
                separator: ';',
            },
            dist: {
                src: ['app/js/**/*.js', '!app/concat.js',
                dest: 'app/concat.js'
            }
        },

        watch: {
            karma: {
                files: ['app/js/**/*.js', 'jasmine/spec/**/*.js'],
                tasks: ['karma:unit:run']
            },

            concat: {
                files: ['app/js/**/*.js', '!app/concat.js'],
                tasks: ['concat']
            },

            live: {
                files: ['app/js/**/*.js', '!app/concat.js', 'app/partials/**/*.html', 'WEB-INF/jsp/panther.html', 'css/new_style.css', 'css/style.css'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },

        karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'jasmine/karma.conf.js',
                background: true
            }
        },

        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'css/new_style.css': 'css/sass/new_style.scss'
                }
            }
        }
    });


    grunt.registerTask('default', ['karma:unit:start', 'concat', 'watch']);
}
```

I do a watch and on code change i trigger the unit testing and concatenation,

My feeling is that this line:

```
src: ['app/js/**/*.js', '!app/concat.js',
```

is not working properly (at least for the second part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're building to the same directory/files as your source. I think that's a bad idea.

You should keep the files you're working on in one directory (for instance `src`) and let Grunt tasks output to another (for instance `app`). That would at least decrease the risk of duplication.

If you have one task that needs to work on the output of another task, let the first task output to a temporary directory and let the second task read from it.