# JS files getting duplicate in Grunt concat task

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I'm facing a weird issue where my some of the files inside usemin blocks are getting duplicated in Grunt build task after Grunt concat.

I've searched for it and found various answers like [Grunt my code is duplicated in concat.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734199/grunt-my-code-is-duplicated-in-concat-js) but not able to fix the solution.

I'm using default generated Gruntfile.js config (via yoman)

```
    useminPrepare: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html', '<%= yeoman.app %>/index-lt-ie10.html'],
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            flow: {
                html: {
                    steps: {
                        js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                        css: ['cssmin']
                    },
                    post: {}
                }
            }
        }
    }

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        //'wiredep',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concat',
        'ngAnnotate',
        'copy:dist',
        'cdnify',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'filerev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin',
    ]);
```

My usemin block looks like:

```
<!-- build:js({app,.}) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate-loader-partial/angular-translate-loader-partial.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/augment/augment.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Using latest dependencies for all node modules with latest nodejs and npm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the solution by passing `--verbose` flag to `grunt build` command. The problem was that there was two `bower_components`, one in my current directory (.) and another with at `./app` directory and since my usemin blocks  `build:js({app,.})` were reading for both the locations i.e. `.` and `./app`, so Grunt's concat task was duplicating all files.

```
Reading ./bower_components/angular/angular.js...OK
Reading app/bower_components/angular/angular.js...OK
Reading ./bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js...OK
Reading app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js...OK
Reading ./bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js...OK
Reading app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js...OK
Reading ./bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js...OK
Reading app/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js...OK
Reading ./bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js...OK
Reading app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js...OK
Reading ./bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js...OK
Reading app/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js...OK
Reading ./bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js...OK
Reading app/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js...OK
Reading ./bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js...OK
Reading app/bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js...OK
Reading ./bower_components/angular-translate-loader-partial/angular-translate-loader-partial.js...OK
Reading app/bower_components/angular-translate-loader-partial/angular-translate-loader-partial.js...OK
Reading ./bower_components/augment/augment.js...OK
Reading app/bower_components/augment/augment.js...OK
```

Hence, removing the `bower_components` directory from `app` directory fixed the problem. Hope this may help to others.